# Does wsl2 support directly execute windows command?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

In wsl, we can directly in bash execute windows command, e.g. `calc` to launch a windows calculator on windows.

Now, wsl2 is there, which said use a hyper-v machine. I wonder, if I upgrade to wsl2, could I still call windows application directly from linux shell?

I haven't upgrade by windows10 to support wsl2, I want to first have above information learnt. If not support direct windows command call from linux shell, I won't upgrade my windows10.

Comment: [You’re not forced to use WSL2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-faq#what-will-happen-to-wsl-1-will-it-be-abandoned), even if you upgrade Windows.

Comment: @DanielB I'm in a restricted environment. If I decide to upgrade windows, I need to submit tickets to persuade guys to upgrade for me. In fact I did not care if it's force or not to use wsl2 on new windows. I just care if wsl2 bash could directly execute windows command just like wsl. Then, I could persuade related to upgrade our restricted environment os.

Comment: Current WSL features will work exactly how they currently work.  The only thing that changes is that WSL will run an actual kernel instead of the way it currently works

Comment: @Ramhound, did you have post to let me have a detail learn. I'm just curious: when `docker for windows` use hyper-v, it will set a hyper-v machine which run linux, then docker container could not execute windows app. How about wsl2? It said it use hyper-v, so per your saying, this means wsl2 not setup a hyper-v machine for wsl2 linux? It use another scheme?

Comment: @atline - "when docker for windows uses hyper-v, it will set a hyper-v machine which runs Linux" - This isn't true.  WSL2 is separate from Hyper-V.  `Docker for Windows` uses Hyper-V not WSL2

Comment: `Docker for windows` use hyper-v, see [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/linux-containers). So, when you say, WSL2 is separate from Hyper-V, you mean the way WSL2 use hyper-v is different with `Microsoft did for docker for windows`?